# Run a local exe by clicking link (from e-mail)

Tags: email, hyperlink, localhost, exe

Is there any way to run a local exe by clicking a link in an e-mail?
In this case i would also like to send a parameter, something like

```
'c:\foo.exe bar'
```

That is, i get the email, click the link and it should start `c:\foo.exe bar` as if i wrote this line in windows by Start->Go (i think it was called "go" back in the days?)

Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i solved it by a quite ugly solution.

Instead of sending a link in the email, i'm sending a temporary written bat-file with the command (`C:\foo.exe bar`) that the reciever has to execute and then the bat runs the exe with the valid parameter. This is for internal use only, but i guess it can be some troubles with virus warnings and stuff. But what to do.

If someone has a better solution, please provide it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a server side language to pass the parameter to the email. You might develope a program that receive the email param and must have permissions to run the EXE desired.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not really following. More specific? If i in the email has like <a href='c:\foo.exe'>Start</a> it asks me if i want to run the exe or save it. If i pass the variable it says it can't find the file. How would i pass the variable? "You might develope a program that receive the email param", how?

Comment: If you do it with PHP, an example of a link would be: <a href="program.php?email=johndoe@johndoe.com">link</a>. If you did the program with PHP, you should review the role: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Sorry, it's monday you know. :)
Well, it would be awesome to make this work without running (in the php-case) an apache on the client

Comment: I think, without using a Web server (Apache or similar), you can not perform the task you indicate.

Comment: Sounds strange. But maybe it's true.

Comment: To view a simple Web page you need a Web server. If you also want to run an exe program, you need a server side language to throw. However, I hope someone else answer or comment to see if there is any other alternative.